# How to manually set the "default download" file in a Sourceforge project?

Tags: sourceforge

When I update some files on my Sourceforge projects, the last uploaded file is always automatically offered on the download page as the "Looking for the latest version? Download..." and it becomes the default download from the project's front page.

My problem is that, on one project, there is the main source tarball but I also have some optional code components that I want to add to the site. Whenever I add such optional component they become the "latest verison" of my app.

Is there a way to force a file to become the "latest version" of the app so that it stays the default download on the main project page?

Comment: As a workaround I tried to re-upload the main file after I uploaded some optional components and it worked. However, using this method, it breaks the upload history as it considers that the upload date is the one from the latest version of file.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If the wrong file is linked to Download button, you can change it by:

1. Click Files
2. Browse through the folders until you find your preferred file
3. Click the "i" icon at the right of the file's entry in the table of files
4. In the pop-up window, under the Default download for: heading, click Select All
5. Press Save
6. Give it a few minutes, refresh your project page and check the link

Comment: Wasn't sure about this until I refreshed the page. Then it was evident.